# Correct way of specifying mixed models in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have crop yield data from multiple location (`admin3`) and years.
`admin3` is nested within `admin2` and `admin2` is nested within `admin1`

If my intention is to model yield as a function of climate variables and year such that the effect of year on yield is different from different `admin1`, how to specify this in mixed models. Which of the specifications is correct?

```
   lmer(yield ~ rainfall + temperature + heat.stress + year + (1 + year|admin1) + (1|admin2) + (1|admin3), data = dat)
```

**OR**

```
 lmer(yield ~ rainfall + temperature + heat.stress + year + (1|admin1) + (year + 0|admin1) + (1|admin2) + (1|admin3), data = dat)
```